# How to XOR a MD5 hash and return a 32 character string?

Tags: c#

How do I further encrypt a MD5 hash by XOR'ing it with a string of variable size (not bigger than 32 characters) ?

I would like the result of the XOR to be a 32 character string as well.

What i have tried so far is:

- convert the md5 string to binary
- convert second string to binary
- pad second binary with 0's (to the left) until both binaries are of equal length
- iterate the binary representations and XOR them
- convert the XOR'ed result to a string

The approach may be wrong, im not sure how to do it. My problem is, when converting the result of the XOR, it is not a 32 character long string, as I would like it to be.

Sample code (equal length strings in this case):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var md51 = ToBinary(ConvertToByteArray(CalculateMD5Hash("Maaa"), Encoding.ASCII));
        var md52 = ToBinary(ConvertToByteArray(CalculateMD5Hash("Moo"), Encoding.ASCII));

        List<int> xoredResult = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < md51.Length; i++)
        {
            var string1 = md51[i];
            var string2 = md52[i];
            var xor = string1 ^ string2;
            xoredResult.Add(xor);
        }

        var resultingString = string.Join("", xoredResult);
        Console.WriteLine(resultingString.Length);

        var data = GetBytesFromBinaryString(resultingString);
        var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

    }

    public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string str, Encoding encoding)
    {
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }

    public static String ToBinary(Byte[] data)
    {
        return string.Join("", data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
    }

    public static Byte[] GetBytesFromBinaryString(String binary)
    {
        var list = new List<Byte>();

        for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
        {
            String t = binary.Substring(i, 8);

            list.Add(Convert.ToByte(t, 2));
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }

    public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
    {

        // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input

        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();

        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        // step 2, convert byte array to hex string

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)

        {

            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));

        }

        return sb.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused and dizzy at how many times you are going back and fore between string and bytes....

Comment: I agree with Marc, While the answer I posted may solve your main underlying problem, you really should just stop converting everything around to strings and back and just have the functions like `CalculateMD5Hash` return the `byte[]` held in the `hash` variable instead.

Comment: The real question is, why do want to XOR an MD5.  "Encrypting it further" doesn't make sense.  MD5 is already an irreversible hash function.  XOR is an easily reversible obfuscation.  What value are you trying to add?

Comment: Sounds like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why don't you just hash with "salt"? Then your MD5 can be 32 hex characters without any additional work. What problem are you _really_ trying to solve here?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the code is not final, I just copy/pasted different methods from SO and put them together. Anyway, its just a demo. Im just trying to replicate what some other guys are doing in a paper that i read, for educational purposes, so I am not interested in salting the md5 hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xoring a string with what is essentially random bytes is not guaranteed to give you a valid string as a output. Your `var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);` is likely failing because you are passing it a non valid string in byte form. You must use something like `var text = Convert.ToBase64String(data)` to be able to represent the random data without loss of information in the process.